# Objectlistview from c# to vb.net convertion PerCellDecoration

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview

i need some help about the objectlistview in vb.net, i did convert everything from c# to vb.net and also import the BrightIdeasSoftware to the vb.net, all setting and configuration is same as c# but only the Image+title+description is not working except the progress with small icons. the objectlistview is same as the c# everything is same every the imageListLarge,imageListSmall. the c# is working very well from the example, did i do something wrong in convert the code?

i need some pro touch and help 
thanks

here is the convert vb.net

```
    Public Class NamedDescriptionDecoration
        Inherits BrightIdeasSoftware.AbstractDecoration
        Public ImageList As ImageList
        Public ImageName As String
        Public Title As String
        Public Description As String

        Public TitleFont As New Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold)
        Public TitleColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 32, 32, 32)
        Public DescripionFont As New Font("Tahoma", 9)
        Public DescriptionColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 96, 96, 96)
        Public CellPadding As New Size(1, 1)

        Public Overrides Sub Draw(olv As BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView, g As Graphics, r As Rectangle)
            Dim cellBounds As Rectangle = Me.CellBounds
            cellBounds.Inflate(-Me.CellPadding.Width, -Me.CellPadding.Height)
            Dim textBounds As Rectangle = cellBounds

            If Me.ImageList IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ImageName) Then
                g.DrawImage(Me.ImageList.Images(Me.ImageName), cellBounds.Location)
                textBounds.X += Me.ImageList.ImageSize.Width
                textBounds.Width -= Me.ImageList.ImageSize.Width
            End If

            'g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, textBounds)

            ' Draw the title
            Dim fmt As New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap)
            fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
            fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near

            Using b As New SolidBrush(Me.TitleColor)
                g.DrawString(Me.Title, Me.TitleFont, b, textBounds, fmt)
            End Using

            ' Draw the description
            Dim size As SizeF = g.MeasureString(Me.Title, Me.TitleFont, CInt(textBounds.Width), fmt)
            textBounds.Y += CInt(size.Height)
            textBounds.Height -= CInt(size.Height)
            Dim fmt2 As New StringFormat()
            fmt2.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
            Using b As New SolidBrush(Me.DescriptionColor)
                g.DrawString(Me.Description, Me.DescripionFont, b, textBounds, fmt2)
            End Using

        End Sub
    End Class
```

and the original C#

```
public class NamedDescriptionDecoration : BrightIdeasSoftware.AbstractDecoration
{
    public ImageList ImageList;
    public string ImageName;
    public string Title;
    public string Description;

    public Font TitleFont = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
    public Color TitleColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 32, 32, 32);
    public Font DescripionFont = new Font("Tahoma", 9);
    public Color DescriptionColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 96, 96, 96);
    public Size CellPadding = new Size(1, 1);

    public override void Draw(BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView olv, Graphics g, Rectangle r) {
        Rectangle cellBounds = this.CellBounds;
        cellBounds.Inflate(-this.CellPadding.Width, -this.CellPadding.Height);
        Rectangle textBounds = cellBounds;

        if (this.ImageList != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ImageName)) {
            g.DrawImage(this.ImageList.Images[this.ImageName], cellBounds.Location);
            textBounds.X += this.ImageList.ImageSize.Width;
            textBounds.Width -= this.ImageList.ImageSize.Width;
        }

        //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, textBounds);

        // Draw the title
        StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;

        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(this.TitleColor)) {
            g.DrawString(this.Title, this.TitleFont, b, textBounds, fmt);
        }

        // Draw the description
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(this.Title, this.TitleFont, (int)textBounds.Width, fmt);
        textBounds.Y += (int)size.Height;
        textBounds.Height -= (int)size.Height;
        StringFormat fmt2 = new StringFormat();
        fmt2.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(this.DescriptionColor)) {
            g.DrawString(this.Description, this.DescripionFont, b, textBounds, fmt2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make it easier for your peers to help, you should make very clear what debugging steps you have taken already, what you can rule out already and highlight the places in the source where the error should be located. Just posting a whole program stating that "it does not work" is sure to get you bad reputation instead of quick help.

Comment: okok.. understand, i have narrow it down to my problem :) thanks for the input

Comment: Also include the original C# code - this will help isolate conversion issues.

Comment: okie, as c# code i added to the conversion :) thanks.

Comment: The conversion looks perfect - the problem must be elsewhere, perhaps in the designer code to set the properties of the listview.

Comment: it look like the Private Sub objectListView1_FormatCell(sender As Object, e As BrightIdeasSoftware.FormatCellEventArgs) Handles objectListView1.FormatCell
          error in vb.net . Error 1 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

Comment: Problem slove ..... must have Handles objectListView1.FormatCell